# A "_" every-time i use a <a href code

Tags: html

```
... <a href=""http://localhost:8888/PhpProject1/php.php/Php.php"><img src="/PhpProject1/vital1_top_logo.jpg"  height="180" border="0px" > height="180"  border="0px" " ></a>
          type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />  ...
</head>
```

Every time i use this tag appears a "_" on the right of the image

Comment: Are you sure this is your HTML code? It's invalid (and could be the cause of your problem)

Comment: By the looks of it your markup is poory written. this is probably the reason why!

Comment: Use 4 spaces to indent, and you won't have to change each instance of < to &lt;

Answer (score 6):

The code you pasted is borked (double quotes at the beginning of href and an extra '>' in the middle of the img tag) so I'm guessing this isn't a real example. My guess is that you have some kind of whitespace between your img tag and the end of your a tag, like so

```
<a href=".."><img src=".."> </a>
```

which will show up as an underlined space. The whitespace might be a newline too mind you, so you should always keep them tight. For example, the following will produce the same problem

```
<a href="..."><img src="...">
</a>
```

HTH.

Comment: you should use <img/> instead of <img>

Comment: Why? <img> is perfectly valid HTML4 whereas <img/> is XHTML.

Comment: @the_drow: You are right when he is using XHTML, but in case of HTML there are some tags that don't need to be closed like br and img

Answer (score 3):

`<a>` and `<img>` are not allowed in `<head>`

Answer (score 2):

It might help if you'd stick to the HTML syntax, right now this snippet is just gibberish. I tried cleaning it up, but then there's almost nothing left that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You added two double quotes:

```
<a href=""http:
```

Use a single one

```
<a href="http:
```

Comment: actually that's two double quotes and he have to use one double quote. A single quote looks like this: '

Comment: @Tim Büthe: Isn't ' an apostrophe though, and " a quotation mark? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 <a href="http://localhost:8888/PhpProject1/php.php/Php.php"><img src="/PhpProject1/vital1_top_logo.jpg" height="180" border="0px" /></a>
```

Comment: Thank you ... yeah it helped...sory about the misspelling on my html

Comment: The (X)HTML border attribute doesn't allow "px": you need border="0".